# Could I get a second pair of eyes to check if this BMS can be used for charging?

Tags: batteries, charging, bms, cell-balancing

I'm new to electric engineering and electronics in general, so as a first project I'm building a battery using 18650 cells (4S4P). I am aware of the risks when buying from Chinese suppliers on aliexpress, however I'm curious if [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32885792743.html?aff_fcid=98327a72e4254e4fa849e25dceb25de1-1617388131974-02514-AMnm2vF&aff_fsk=AMnm2vF&aff_platform=dynamic-window&sk=AMnm2vF&aff_trace_key=98327a72e4254e4fa849e25dceb25de1-1617388131974-02514-AMnm2vF&terminal_id=c40cd7c158f241fb9a4c0f221e8ae305) BMS supports balanced charging protection. After some research, I believe it does, seeing as there are electrical contacts for each cell, much like a balance cable. I would be extremely grateful for someone else to double check for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but there are different types of balancing circuits. This one is passive (at a glance). It will burn off power if a cell (or multiple, if arranged in parallel) reach max voltage first. The downside is that if the resistor can't "burn down" the extra voltage, you CAN hit an overvoltage event if the cells are out of balance enough.

I'd also point out NOT to assemble it like they did in the photos. All of the (series) current is going through thin wires back to the BMS. You SHOULD use those nickel strips in between the cells, too. There isn't a "functional" or "logical" difference in assembly processes, but just be aware you could have some really bad/weird effects.

Edit: A few additional comments. If you don't know what I mean by passive/active balancing, you should read up on that and understand the differences. If you're using a simple 4S/1P config with new, matched cells, it's unlikely you'll have any real problems with a BMS like this, but if you're salvaging cells, etc., then you should pay close attention to things like capacity, current draw, cell impedance, etc.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I'm going to be using brand new cells so I should be fine. I guess using a passive balancer is less efficient in way, seeing as the excess energy is dissipated as heat instead of being redistributed. Thanks a ton again.